# Pattern for executing common code when using continue inside a Python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

```
validate_input():
    while not_valid:
        attempt += 1
        inpt = prompt_and_get_input()

        if validate_check1(inpt) is False:
            # common code for invalid_state
            continue

        if validate_check2(inpt) is False:
            # common code for invalid_state
            continue

        # ... repeat ....

        not_valid = False # Valid state
```

I would like to factor out the duplicated common code that and place it in only a single location in the loop. I understand that I could put it inside of a function/method, but there would still be duplicated calls.

I would like to do something like:

```
    validate_input():
    while not_valid:
        attempt += 1
        inpt = prompt_and_get_input()

        if validate_check1(inpt) is False:
            continue

        if validate_check2(inpt) is False:
            continue

        # ... repeat ....

        not_valid = False # Valid state
    else:
        # We get here anytime a validate_check() fails via continue
        # common vode for _invalid_state
```

I understand that the `else` clause for a loop will only execute if the loop executes normally (vs. via `break`). I want sort of the opposite functionality where the `xxx` clause only gets executed in the event that the loop *didn't iterate* naturally (i.e. a `continue` statement)

I know there is no built-in feature for this functionality, but is there a better pattern for what I would like to do? This pattern has come up several times in the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an exception with a try/except block.

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass

while not_valid:
    try:
        inpt = prompt_and_get_input()

        if not validate_check1(inpt):
            raise ValidationError()

        ...
    except ValidationError:
        # common code
```

Even better, raise the validation error inside the validate_checkX functions, then you don't even need to check the return value - or even return a value at all.

(Note that if you do return a value, it's extremely unPythonic to compare with False; you should do `if not <whatever>` as I show above.)

Comment: Thank you.  I've been using Python for a few months, but it still seems non-intuitive or even unnatural to raise exceptions that aren't really errors.I know this is the Pythonic way, now I just need to remember that coding.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your input validation should be managed from a single place, something like:

```
def is_valid(input, validators, reaction=None):
   # type: AnyStr, Iterable[Callable[AnyStr, bool]], Callable[AnyStr] -> bool
   for validator in validators:
       if validator(input):
           continue
       if reaction:
           reaction(input)  # You could use partial to modify the reaction
       return False
   return True
```